# XSLT understand about the generate-id working way

Tags: xslt

Further to this link [xslt return selection of following siblings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17301355/xslt-return-selection-of-following-siblings?rq=1)
I Just to want to know, here, what is purpose of this `generate-id` and how it is making sense in this matching protocol.

```
<xsl:for-each select="/items/item[@lcn='005417714']">
  <xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::*[generate-id(preceding-sibling::item[@lcn != ''][1]) = generate-id(current())]">
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Any idea, pls share.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The specification of `generate-id` is that it will always return the same ID for the same node and different IDs for different nodes.  Thus, comparing the `generate-id` values of two nodes is the way you check whether they are *the same node* as opposed to just two nodes that happen to have the same value.

And `current()` gives you the current "top-level" context node - outside a predicate `current()` is the same as `.`, but inside a predicate expression `.` refers to the node the predicate is testing whereas `current()` still refers to the "outer `.`".

Now in your example

```
following-sibling::*[generate-id(preceding-sibling::item[@lcn != ''][1])
                      = generate-id(current())]
```

the outer context node is an `item` element (the one that the outer `for-each` is currently looking at).  So starting from that `item` the expression will select:

```
following-sibling::*                      --- all the following sibling elements
 [                                        --- such that
  generate-id(                            --- the identity of
   preceding-sibling::item[@lcn != ''][1] --- that element's nearest preceding
                                              item with a non-empty lcn attribute
  )
  =                                       --- is the same as
  generate-id(current())                  --- the identity of the item we started
                                              with
 ]
```

in other words, all the sibling elements between this `<item lcn="005417714">` (exclusive) and the next `<item lcn="anything-non-empty">` (inclusive).

Taking an example from the linked question:

```
<item id="00100687" label="A/161i r" lcn="005417714" notes="A/161-182"/>
<item id="00100688" label="A/161i v" lcn="" notes=""/>
<item id="00100819" label="A/182ii v" lcn="" notes=""/>
<item id="00100820" label="A/182iii r" lcn="" notes=""/>
<item id="00100821" label="A/182iii v" lcn="" notes=""/>
<item id="00100822" label="A/183i r" lcn="005417715" notes="A/183-218"/>
<item id="00100823" label="A/183i v" lcn="" notes=""/>
<item id="00100975" label="A/216iii r" lcn="" notes=""/>
```

if the current context node is the `item` with `id="00100687"` then that select would pull out items 00100688, 00100819, 00100820, 00100821 and 00100822.  If you wanted to exclude 00100822 you'd have to add another predicate

```
following-sibling::*[@lcn = '']
                    [generate-id(preceding-sibling::item[@lcn != ''][1])
                      = generate-id(current())]
```